# IntelliJ IDEA prettier plugin does not apply given configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, prettier

I installed the IntelliJ Prettier plugin for web development. Unfortunately I was not able to specifiy a custom configuration, which consists of this line: `"prettier.singleQuote": true`.

What I tried:
Under `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Prettier` I specified once the global and once the project specific prettier installation. (In the screenshot you'll see the global package). [image]

Not regarding configuration file I tried creating a `.prettierrc` file in my projects' root where the `package.json` lies. The config file looks like this

.prettierrc

```
{
  "prettier.printWidth": 5,
  "prettier.trailingComma": "none",
  "prettier.singleQuote": true
}
```

Since this didn't work I renamed it to `.prettierrc.json` which didn't work either. Then I tried to use the "prettier" tag in my projects' `package.json` like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.5.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.13.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "prettier.singleQuote": true
  },
```

Still when I format with `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+P` it only applies the default configuration and not the provided one, thus replacing all existing single to double-quotes.

I also tried a few things mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000167624-How-can-I-change-the-prettier-settings-) (IntelliJ Forum), which didn't work for me either. What am I missing? (Tried also a desperate IDEA restart ...)

Comment: have you tried by configuring in external tools ?

Comment: see comment on your answer.

Comment: can you please ping me the link which you referred

Comment: the link im referring to is already a hyperlink on my question. Just click on the "here".

Answer (score 6):

I assume prettier is installed.
To configure prettier you have go > Settings > Tools > External Tools
Create prettier action, [image] Follow screenshot for commands.

Follow below steps to apply prettier on js file

1. Open a file
2. Hit Ctrl+shift+a or Right click on file >  External Tools > Prettier (action name)
3. Type your action name (prettier name which you given)
4. Hit Enter

please [click](https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html) here for more info on this.

Comment: I assume that this will work, but it would be just a workaround to the problem unfortunately. It should be working with the provided plugin for IDEA version 2018.1 and above as stated here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html

Comment: For now I'm using the suggested workaround, but I'll still wait for someone using the prettier intellij plugin, who got it running.

Answer (score 6):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002745119-How-to-have-Reformat-Code-feature-behave-exactly-like-Prettier-

"You can re-import settings at any time using Apply Prettier Code Style Rules in the .prettierrc right-click menu:

[image]

"